# Selected option does not run script

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the HTML `<select>` for selecting options. The first value in my select is `selected`. For all of these options I have a javascript that runs different scripts.

When I change the value to 2 the javascript runs the script for value 2 `(dataEl.value === "2") { outputEl.innerHTML = '<div>result option two</div>';`

The script works only when the value is changed and does not show the script for value 1 when the selected option is not changed.

Does someone know how I can solve this?

Here is my script:

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/yua9vanz/

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Select</label>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
    <select class="form-control select2" id="select" name="select" style="width: 100%;">
      <option selected="selected" value="1">Option one</option>
      <option value="2">Option two</option>
      <option value="3">Option three</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<p id="output1"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var dataEl = document.querySelector('#select'),
  outputEl = document.querySelector('#output1');

  dataEl.onchange = function() {
    if (dataEl.value === "1") {
      outputEl.innerHTML = '<div>result option one</div>';

    } else if (dataEl.value === "2") {
      outputEl.innerHTML = '<div>result option two</div>';

    } else if (dataEl.value === "3") {
      outputEl.innerHTML = '<div>result option three</div>';
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want your function to be called when the page loads? Just add `dataEl.onchange()` to your script.

Comment: I want both. I want to show `<div>result option one</div>` when the select is not changed an run the `dataEl.onchange = function()`  when the value is changed. Currently the second part (dataEl.onchange) is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want, I modified the code a bit, but in summary, I just added the [`onload`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) event in the element(`#select`).

```js
var dataEl = document.querySelector('#select'),
  outputEl = document.querySelector('#output1');

dataEl.addEventListener("load", check());

function check() {
  if (dataEl.value === "1") {
    outputEl.innerHTML = '<div>result option one</div>';

  } else if (dataEl.value === "2") {
    outputEl.innerHTML = '<div>result option two</div>';

  } else if (dataEl.value === "3") {
    outputEl.innerHTML = '<div>result option three</div>';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Select</label>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
    <select class="form-control select2" id="select" name="select" style="width: 100%;" onchange="check()">
      <option selected="selected" value="1">Option one</option>
      <option value="2">Option two</option>
      <option value="3">Option three</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<p id="output1"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I meant:

```js
var dataEl = document.querySelector('#select'),
  outputEl = document.querySelector('#output1');

dataEl.onchange = function() {
  if (dataEl.value === "1") {
    outputEl.innerHTML = '<div>result option one</div>';
  } else if (dataEl.value === "2") {
    outputEl.innerHTML = '<div>result option two</div>';
  } else if (dataEl.value === "3") {
    outputEl.innerHTML = '<div>result option three</div>';
  }
};

dataEl.onchange();
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Select</label>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
    <select class="form-control select2" id="select" name="select" style="width: 100%;" onchange="check()">
      <option selected="selected" value="1">Option one</option>
      <option value="2">Option two</option>
      <option value="3">Option three</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<p id="output1"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `onclick` event (and optionally `onkeypress`to detect keyboard navigation).

Just to clarify what the `selected`attribute does (source: [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)):

> When present, it specifies that an option should be pre-selected when
>   the page loads.
>
> The pre-selected option will be displayed first in the drop-down list.

So, if you want to run the script without user intervention, simply run it:

`dataEl.onchange();`

Comment: But I want to run the script when nothing is done. The script needs to show `<div>result option one</div>` when the value is not changed

Comment: you mean, you need to display the default selected value at page load?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, though not ideal, is the following:

```
var dataEl = document.querySelector('#select');

showResult(dataEl);
dataEl.onchange = function() {
    showResult(dataEl);
};

function showResult(selector) {
      var outputEl = document.querySelector('#output1');
      if (selector.value === "1") {
        outputEl.innerHTML = '<div>result option one</div>';

      } else if (selector.value === "2") {
        outputEl.innerHTML = '<div>result option two</div>';

      } else if (selector.value === "3") {
        outputEl.innerHTML = '<div>result option three</div>';
      }
}
```

All it does is call a function to get the selected value, both at page load and when the selected value changes.